# Remove anchor links from URL with Smooth-Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

New to StackOverflow here so please let me know if there's anything I need to do.

I'm using cferdinanadi's smooth-scroll plug-in on my website (https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) but I want to get rid of the anchor links in my URL once I click on a link. So right now when I click on a link, my URL becomes (www.mysite.com/#anchor) but I want it to stay as (www.mysite.com)

At the very bottom of the provided documentation (https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll), I found the helper function that should remove those anchor links from the URL but I'm unsure where I should paste the code to make it work.

Can anyone help me? Here's the code provided that should fix it:

```
var scroll = new SmoothScroll();

var smoothScrollWithoutHash = function (selector, settings) {
    /**
     * If smooth scroll element clicked, animate scroll
     */
    var clickHandler = function (event) {
        var toggle = event.target.closest( selector );
        console.log(toggle);
        if ( !toggle || toggle.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a' ) return;
        console.log(toggle.hash);
        var anchor = document.querySelector( toggle.hash );
        if ( !anchor ) return;

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default click event
        scroll.animateScroll( anchor, toggle, settings || {} ); // Animate scroll
    };

    window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false );
};

// Run our function
smoothScrollWithoutHash( 'a[href*="#"]' );
```

Comment: Can you share screen shot of what you have and what you want? Also it would be helpful if you can provide a link to your site or jsfiddler.

Comment: The site is not up yet. I'll add this edit in the post as well but right now my URL becomes (mysite.com/#section1) when I click on a link but I want it to remain as (www.mysite.com)

Comment: Above `var toggle ...` add `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I ended up just using a workaround.

For anyone else trying to figure this out, just add:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    history.replaceState ("", document.title, e.originalEvent.oldURL);
});
```

to the bottom of the .js file.